# Python 2.7 problems with sub-classing dict and mirroring to json

Tags: python, json, python-2.7, dictionary, subclass

So I am trying to create a class that behaves like a dict but also copies itself to a .json file whenever a change is made to the dict. I've got it working for the most part; but where I have trouble is when I append something to a list inside the dict; it updates the dict but not the .json file associated with the dict.

I am sorry for the lengthy code block, I tried to condense as much as possible but it still turned out fairly lengthy.

```
import json
import os.path

class JDict(dict):
    def __init__(self, filepath, *args, **kwargs):
        if str(filepath).split('.')[-1] == 'json':
            self.filepath = str(filepath)
        else:
            self.filepath = str('{}.json'.format(filepath))

        if os.path.isfile(self.filepath):
            super(JDict, self).__init__(self.read())
        else:
            super(JDict, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
            self.write()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        dict.__setitem__(self, key, value)
        self.write()

    def write(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'w') as outfile:
            json.dump(self, outfile, sort_keys = True, indent = 4,
                ensure_ascii=False)

    def read(self):
        with open(self.filepath, 'r') as infile:
            jsonData = json.load(infile)
        self = jsonData
        return self

def parseJson(filepath):
    with open(filepath, 'r') as infile:
        jsonData = json.load(infile) 
    return jsonData

test = JDict("test.json", {
    "TestList": [
        "element1"
        ]
    })

test["TestList"].append("element2")

try:
    if test["TestList"][1] == parseJson("test.json")["TestList"][1]:
        print 'Success'
except IndexError:
    print 'Failure'
```

Comment: I tried it, it works.

Comment: It didn't print 'Failure' to the console? It printed 'Success'? I wrote it in such a way that it doesn't crash...it just prints success or failure depending on of it mimics the behavior I am wanting it to achieve. @SergeyGornostaev

Comment: Print 'Success' and json changing.

Comment: @SergeyGornostaev What version of python are you using? because that doesn't seem right. I've been doing some tests and `dict.__setitem__` isn't even triggered on `dict.list.append()` at least not in python 27

EDIT: Just launched in python3 still not working. :(

Comment: `test["TestList"].append("element2")` doesn't touch `self.__setitem__()` because you *read* TestList but never write to it.
add a test["TestList"] = test["TestList"] right after and it should work.

Comment: @gbin well that is a good workaround, but I am looking for a way to COMPLETELY emulate the functionality of lists and dicts while also writing to a Json...Right now I am experimenting with sub-classing "list" as well...

Comment: @DustinNunyo This gonna be tricky because if the user of your class insert a full subtree, you'll need to recursively swap all the elements of the tree...

Comment: @gbin I actually think I've done it feel free to check it out; [Click Here](https://github.com/deeredman1991/QJson/blob/master/QJson.py)

Answer (score 0):

So the reason I was having trouble was because **setitem** isn't called on the dict (or even on a list for that matter) when you append an element to a member list.

Soooo...if anyone else is having this issue; I ended up sub-classing both list and dict datatypes and making them sort of helper classes to a new class called QJson

all lists and dicts under the helper class QJson get converted to JDicts and JLists respectively.

and QJson is itself a dict

The code is REALLY long and monolithic at this point so here is a link to my [github](https://github.com/deeredman1991/QJson/blob/master/QJson.py) enjoy. :)